# Absolutely continuous measure and equality to $0$

Tags: measure-theory, absolute-continuity, radon-nikodym

In the context of proving that the data processing inequality for $f$-divergences hold for any Markov kernel I am interested in the following statement

> If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two probability measures on a probability space $(X,\Sigma,\mathbb P)$ such that $\nu\ll\mu$ and $f$ is any function from $X$ to $[0,1]$, then for $A\in \Sigma$
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_A f~ d\mu = 0 \Rightarrow \int_A f ~d\nu = 0
> \end{align*}

Does anyone knows about this ? Is it even true ? I tried to prove it using the Radon-Nikodym derivative without success.

Comment: Decompose $A=\{x\in A:\ 0\leq f(x)<1/n\}\cup\{x\in A:\ f(x)\geq1/2\}=A_{1,n}\cup A_{2,n}$. If $0=\int_Afd\mu=\int_{A_{1,n}}fd\mu+\int_{A_{2,n}}fd\mu\geq\mu(A{2,n})/n$. Therefore, $\mu(A_{2,n})=0$. Since $\{f\neq0\}=\bigcup_nA_{2,n}$ we get that the set where $f\neq0$ has $\mu$-measure zero. Therefore, it also has $\nu$-measure zero. It follows that $\int_Afd\nu=0$.

Comment: Alternatively, here's the Radon-Nikodym argument: $\nu\ll\mu\implies \nu=g\mu\implies f\nu=fg\mu\implies f\nu\ll f\mu$.